# Group of order 4 cannot have element of order 3

Tags: group-theory

The question says that group of order $4$ cannot have an element of order $3$. We are given the hint “if it did, then, calling the elements $e, a, a^2, b$, with $a^3$=e, deduce a contradiction using the cancellation law”.

I’m not too sure on how to start the question and I would appreciate any hints to help me answer this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Further hint: you can’t assign a value to ab without violating the cancellation law somehow

Comment: Hint. Try each of the four possible things $ab$ might be.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Consider the element $ab$. It should be equal to one of $e,a,a^2,b$. Find a contradiction for each case.

For instance: if $ab=e$, $\;b=a^{-1}=a^2$, hence the group has $3$ elements, not $4$.

Comment: Why does b=$a^{-1}$ also equal $a^2$

Comment: Because $a$ has order $3$, i.e. $a^3=a\cdot a^2=e$.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear.

Answer (score 2):

This a direct application of Lagrange’s theorem: if $a$ were of order $3$, then $3$ would have to be a divisor of $4$.

Answer (score 1):

There are some theorems which will make this immediate but I'm assuming you're not familiar with them. So consider this: the order of a group is the number of elements in the group. So, follow the hint and WLOG define $G=\{e,a,a^2,b\}$ with the order of $a$ as $3$.

Now, it follows that $ab$ must be equal to one of these elements. If $ab=e$, it implies that $a^2=b$. If $ab=a$, $b=e$, if $ab=a^2$, $a=b$ and $ab=b\Rightarrow a=e$, all of which are contradictions to the order of $G$ being $4$.